# FAST conversion from MTS to MP4 (OS X)

Tags: macos, hdvideo, video-conversion

I have tried using [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) but it's quite slow (4fps!). IMovie 08 is faster but requires the camera to be plugged in (i.e., it can't work with the MTS directly). Are there are any better (even pay) solutions?

**Edit:** This [program](http://www.moviesmac.com/video-converter-mac/) is pay and perhaps even  slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [VoltaicHD](http://www.shedworx.com/voltaichd), another pay-for ffmpeg-based program - I've had luck with that myself but it's still slow.

The fastest in my experience is using iMovie or Final Cut Pro's built in importer. You can import the files without plugging in the camera by doing either of the following:

1. Copy the entire AVCHD folder (not just the .m2t files - it's important to have all the folders and relevant metadata in the folder structure) to your hard drive and then point Final Cut Pro's Log and Transfer at that folder

   OR
2. Create a disk image of the camera using Disk Utility. Once completed you can unmount the camera and mount the disk image and as far as iMovie and Final Cut are concerned it's just as if the camera was plugged in and they'll auto detect the footage.

   To create the disk image, choose "New Disk Image from <NAME OF CAMERA> (eg. NO NAME)" in the File menu.

Comment: +1000 this is great. Very far-fetched (esp. #2), but if it works I'm in. I'll check out faking out IMovie too. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like switching Handbrake to the ffmpeg conversion makes it go much faster. What am I losing (for video editing) by not using H.264 (?) encoding?

Comment: Worked for IMovie 8 too. The ffmpeg conversion was not usable by Final Cut Pro, so that ends that.

Comment: @Yar: #2 is what we actually use for archiving and importing of AVCHD at the post house I work at. iMovie and FCP don't use H.264 as a native editing format so the movie will be converted once more into AIC (iMovie) or ProRes (FCP).

Comment: Thanks @Chealion, that makes sense: I wish there were an easier, FASTER solution too all this, but for some technical reason it's not possible to speed it up.

Comment: @Chealion, I imagine that you meant to say "You can import the files without plugging in the camera by doing EITHER OF the following:"... I'm so relieved that the disk image isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Pavtube (payware):

http://www.pavtube.com/video-converter-mac/

(Maybe also see Turbo264HD by elgato).

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if that's the same one I mentioned in the Q. However: now I realize that if the final destination is Final Cut Pro, I have to use Final Cut Pro to import.

Comment: [Pavtube is a violator of the GPL](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4239).